# touchesBegan on a node to delete it

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touchesbegan

per exemple, I have a SKSpriteNode generated in a function named "generateNode" every seconds, and I want to call it in the touchesBegin function to detect when the user touch it, and if the user touch it, the node is deleted.

I tried to call the node in this function, but it is impossible, Xcode doesn't detect it in this function.

How to do that ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Do you have any code you've done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a particular node in the following way.

First set the `node.name` property at the place where you add it.

```
func generateNode() {
    // your node creation code
    node.name = "generatedNode"
    //add your node.
}
```

Then in `touchesBegan`, you can remove the touched node if the name of the node is the name you set.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch?
    if let location = touch?.locationInNode(self)
    {
        for node in self.nodesAtPoint(location)
        {
            if node.name == "generatedNode"
            {
                node.removeFromParent()
            }
        }

    }
}
```